# Find value of expression

Tags: numerical-methods

$$\begin{matrix}
x'=-y \\ 
y'=-x'
\end{matrix}  \begin{matrix}
x(0)=1\\ 
y(0)=0
\end{matrix}$$ Calculate with the explicit Euler's method the expression $A=(x_n)^2+(y_n)^2$, where $x_n, y_n$ are the approximations at the step $n$.

The problem can be written as $$\binom{x}{y}'=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\binom{x}{y} $$

Applying the explicit Euler's method we get $$\binom{x_{n+1}}{y_{n+1}}=\binom{x_n}{y_n}+h\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\binom{x_n}{y_n}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -h\\ 
-h & 1
\end{pmatrix}\binom{x_n}{y_n} $$

So we have $$
(x_{n+1})^2+(y_{n+1})^2=(x_n-hy_n)^2+(-hx_n+y_n)^2=(1+h^2)[(x_n)^2+(y_n)^2]-4hx_ny_n$$

How can we find a general formula for $(x_n)^2+(y_n)^2$ ?

For $n=0$ we have $(x_1)^2+(y_1)^2=1+h^2$.

For $n=1$ we have $(x_2)^2+(y_2)^2=(1+h^2)^2-4xhx_1y_1$.

Comment: That comma floating in midair in your first display --- what's that about?

Comment: The comma has been replaced with a prime, so the second equation now says $x$ and $y$ have the same derivative --- is that really right?

Answer (score 1):

Still using matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{n+1}\\y_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -h\\ 
-h & 1
\end{pmatrix}^{n+1}\binom{x_0}{y_0}$$

You can find the eigenvalues of this matrix. There are two real ones. Then find its diagonalization to find the power. That would give you an explicit expression.

Comment: I found that $\binom{x^n}{y^n}= \binom{\frac{1}{2} (1+h)^n+ \frac{1}{2} (1-h)^n}{-\frac{1}{2} (1+h)^n+ \frac{1}{2}(1-h)^n}$.
$$$$
So I found $\binom{x^2}{y^2}=\binom{5}{-4}$. Am I right?

Comment: @evinda: My second component is $\frac{1}{2} (1+h)^n- \frac{1}{2}(1-h)^n$.

Comment: @evinda: Also, did you mean $x_n,y_n$ and $x_2,y_2$?

Comment: Isn't it the same, with the only difference that we took other coefficients when finding the igenvectors? Yes, that's what I meant... $$$$

I will take a look again at my calculations.

$$$$
Could you maybe also take a  look at my other question?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331318/smallest-possible-number-of-steps

Comment: @evinda: I don't think they are the same, because they give different answers. And from my calculation, $x_2=1+h^2, y_2=2h$. How did you get $5, -4$??

Comment: Could you maybe take a look at my question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505467/show-upper-bound ?