# Smallest possible number of steps

Tags: numerical-methods

We have the following Runge Kutta Butcher tableau:

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccccc} 
\tau_1 =0 & a_{11}=0 & a_{12} = 0\\ 
\tau_2 =\frac{3}{2} & a_{21} = \frac{3}{2} & a_{22} = 0\\ 
\hline
& b_1 = \frac{2}{3} & b_2 = \frac{1}{3} & \ 
\end{array} $$

$$y'=-10y \\ y(0)=1$$

For which $h$ do we have the smallest possible number of steps?

1. $h=0.5$
2. $h=0.01$
3. $h=0.02$
4. $h=0.1$

I found that the approximation is $$y^{n+1}=y^n+\frac{2}{3}hf(t^n, y^n)+\frac{1}{3}hf(t^n+\frac{h}{3}, y^n+\frac{3h}{2}f(t^n, y^n)) \\ \Rightarrow y^{n+1}=y^n-\frac{2}{3}h10y^n-\frac{h}{3}10(y^n+\frac{3h}{2}(-10y^n)) \\ \Rightarrow y^{n+1}=y^n(1-10h+50h^2)$$

Is this correct?

So the method is stable when $$|1-10h+50h^2| \leq 1 \\ \Rightarrow h<\frac{1}{5} $$ 
The options 2,3,4 satisfy this inequality.

Since we want the smallest number of steps we take the largest h, so $h=0.1$

Is this correct?

Or do we not use the absolute stability to find the $h$ ?

Comment: Is it a typo that you have $3/2$ in your tableau, but $1/3$ in your equation?

Comment: I edited my post... @KittyL

Comment: Should be $1-10h+50h^2$.

Comment: @KittyL I reedited my post.

Comment: I think it is correct now.

Comment: Looks good to me.